# Flash memory usage in browser?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

When I run my swf locally in the Flash Player application, its memory usage starts at around 50 Mb, and though it definitely fluctuates, it generally stays centered at around 50 Mb.

Then I embed the same swf in an html page and run it in my browser (firefox). Now the memory usage starts at 20 Mb, but increases at a near constant rate until it is over 100 Mb and I need to stop it. The swf is essentially unusable in the browser because of this.

What could be the cause of this huge difference in behavior? Where should I even begin when trying to make the swf functional in the browser?

**EDIT:** I have found what was causing the problem (sort of). A certain type of object, which gets spawned a lot during the game, doesn't respond to removeChild() correctly. As a result these types of objects were building up on the stage (but invisible) and causing the memory usage to skyrocket. This doesn't occur when I test it in CS4 or in the standalone flash player application, only in the browser. It seems like a Flash bug.

Thank you to everyone who responded, you have indirectly caused me to find the weird problem!

Comment: Firefox consuming 100MB for one page? Nothing unusual in itself :) Does this happen in other browsers as well? Is this really causing problems? In what form?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This is a game, and it gets very choppy over time. The choppiness seems to correlate with the memory usage so I'm (maybe incorrectly) assuming they are linked.

Comment: Can you try if this also happens in other browsers, and maybe other versions of Firefox (e.g. try using a fresh install without any AddOns and with a fresh profile).

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome and Safari, and in each of these browsers the memory usage behaves the same way, constantly increasing until the game is unplayable. However, something strange did happen in these browsers that might be an important hint: a DisplayObject that is supposed to be removed from the stage and eventually garbage collected (and that definitely is when the game is tested not in the browser) instead snaps to the upper left corner of the screen and stays there. This didn't happen in Firefox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was causing the problem (sort of). A certain type of object, which gets spawned a lot during the game, doesn't respond to removeChild() correctly. As a result these types of objects were building up on the stage (but invisible) and causing the memory usage to skyrocket. This doesn't occur when I test it in CS4 or in the standalone flash player application, only in the browser. It seems like a Flash bug.

Thank you to everyone who responded, you have indirectly caused me to find the weird problem!

Comment: An object doesn't respond to removeChild() if it has strong reference which are not set to null. and CS4 uses Flash player 10 and your browser may be using Flash player 9.

Answer (score 0):

Probably player using memory cache. In chrome web browser you can go to the task manager and if your browser using flash player, you can see memory usage of flash plugin used by chrome.
In my opinion it's all obout player configuration.

Comment: Hm... what should I be looking for in the task manager of Chrome? Right now I just see the memory of the Flash Player plugin increasing in parallel with the memory usage the swf itself is reporting.

Comment: look at the nert statistics - you can see the private/shared/total even virtual memory statistic - what you can read from those data depends of you and typical flash application.